# Where to download the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio and SDK Tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/). However, the studio asks about SDK path and when I provide the tools folder, it says it is not valid. When I search for SDK, pages refer to the studio page. Where can I download the SDK manager?

[image]

Comment: See here https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDK manager is available under `Tools` menu of Android Studio:

[image: SDK manager]

By default Android Studio downloads the SDK on `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

You can select this dir in your Android Studio.

If you don't find the `SDK Manager` then download the [sdk-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads). You will SDK Manager under `bin` folder

Comment: That folder is empty. The figure I shown is at the point of opening a project. Without specifying the sdk path, it won't proceed to the studio

Comment: @mahmood are you able to locate SDK Manager and install the packages?

Comment: @mahmood you check my answer

Comment: From the startup page (new, open project, ...), I see "configure". Then a window opens "Default Settings". Under Appearance->system_settings->android_sdk, it is still asking for a path

Comment: @mahmood Check the `Show Package Details` and install required version

Comment: OK. It seems that for the first time I open studio, it will automatically download the sdk  via internet. Since, the vm wasn't connected to internet, it asked for the path! It SHOULD show a message that no internet connection is available. But it doesn't!! After connecting to internet, I opened sdk again and now it is downloading the sdk. Thanks

Comment: @mahmood great! Thanks for updating

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just closed the popup asking for the SDk path as I had deleted the whole sdk folder files. Even though the Android Studio software states it can't continue without a SDk installation, I was able to click the errors away and like stated above start the SDk manager.

I **pointed the SDK path to my empty sdk folder** and then it gave a list of files it was
going to (download and) install. After that (when the first download and installation
completes) you can further configure the packages to your needs. it will then further download and install the selected packages. I hope this helps. (pls give it a thumbs up;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can find here

click tools from android studio( from toolbar) -> click android-> sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Where can I find the sdk manager?
You can find it Top of android studio window **Tools-->SDK Manager**

You should give the SDK Location path that is generally available at
**/home/user/Android/Sdk**.

Try this..!